# Localization and direct limit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory

Let $ A $ be a ring.

Let $ I $ be a preordered set, filtering.

Let $ \Sigma $ a multiplicative subset of $ A $.

Suppose for any given $ i \in I $ a multiplicative subset $ S_i $ of $ A $ contained in $ \Sigma $.

Make the following assumptions:

- $ \Sigma = \displaystyle \bigcup_i S_i $
- For $ (i, j) \in I^2 $ with $ i \leq j $, elements $ S_i $ become invertible in $ S_ {j}^{-1} A $.

$ \mathcal{D} = ((S_{i}^{-1} A)_{i \in I} \ , \ (S_{i}^{-1} A \to S_{j}^{-1} A)_{i \leq j}) $ is a commutative diagram in the category of filter $ A $ - algebras.

**Question** :

Show that $ \displaystyle \lim_{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{D} \simeq \Sigma^{-1} A $.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try to use the universal properties of both objects?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Sorry.

Comment: What is $f_{i,j}$?

Comment: It's : $ f_{i,j} : S_{i}^{-1} A \to S_{j}^{-1} A $.

Answer (score 1):

$\Sigma^{-1} A$ represents the functor of homomorphisms on $A$ which invert all elements in $\Sigma$. Since $\Sigma$ is covered by the $S_i$, this means that all the $S_i$ are made invertible. Hence, we get unique lifts to $S_i^{-1} A$, and these are clearly compatible. The construction is invertible, so that $\Sigma^{-1} A$ represents the same functor as $\varinjlim_i S_i^{-1}A$, i.e. they are isomorphic (Yoneda Lemma).

Comment: We must show that:
$ 1) $ exist morphisms $ \pi_i: S_{i}^{-1} A \to \Sigma^{-1} A $ such that $ \pi_{i + p} f_{i, i + p } = \pi_ {i} $.
$ 2) $ for any group $ B $ equipped with morphisms $ \pi_i: S_ {i}^{-1} A \to B $ such that $ p_{i + p} f_{i, i + p} = p_{i} $ there exists a unique morphism $ g : \Sigma^{-1} a \to B $ such that $ p_i = g \circ \pi_i $.
But, i d'ont know how to do it.

Comment: You don't have to do this that way. Recall the Yoneda Lemma.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i need to use this definition, because, i have to go step by step ... I don"t want to go directly to Yoneda lemma now ... Thanks a lot for your help.